# Escopo de atualização do p:ajax e validação

Tags: java, jsf

Preciso que ao alterar o valor do input LevelNo para **0** o input factoryCode seja desabilitado, e caso contrario nada deve acontecer. Tenho o seguinte código:

```
       <p:inputMask id="LevelNo" size="4" maxlength="9" mask="9?99999999" slotChar="" style="text-align: right;" value="#{MeuManageBean.requestDTO.levelNo}" rendered="#{MeuManageBean.mode eq 'MODE_NEW_REGISTER' or MeuManageBean.mode eq 'MODE_COPY_NEW' or MeuManageBean.mode eq 'MODE_EDIT'}">
          <f:validateLongRange minimum="0" />
          <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true"/>
          <p:ajax event="change" process=" @this"  update="@form" listener="#{MeuManageBean.enableOrDisableFieldsByLevelNo}" /> 
       </p:inputMask>  

       <p:inputText id="factoryCode" size="4" value="#{MeuManageBean.requestDTO.factoryCode}"  rendered="#{MeuManageBean.mode eq 'MODE_NEW_REGISTER' or MeuManageBean.mode eq 'MODE_COPY_NEW' or (MeuManageBean.mode eq 'MODE_EDIT' and MeuManageBean.disabledFieldsLevelZero == false) }" readonly="#{MeuManageBean.disabledFieldsLevelZero}" required="true">
          <f:converter converterId="com.projeto.converter.UpperCaseConverter" />
       </p:inputText>
```

Da forma que está, quando eu altero o valor do campo factoryCode e logo em seguida altero o valor do LevelNo, o jsf apaga o valor do campo factoryCode, pois na arvore de componente o valor ainda é "", caso seja para desabilitar o sistema tem o comportamento esperado, no caso contrario o comportamento esperado pelo usuário é que o valor seja mantido.

Se eu coloco o factoryCode no process do ajax, o sistema apresenta o erro de validação, pois o campo é requerido, não posso colocar o immediate="true", pois preciso que o componente seja atualizado com "", caso já tenha sido preenchido e possuo outros comportamentos que preciso manter mesmo no ajax, pois isso é apenas parte do meu código.

Alguém tem alguma idéia, de como conseguir o comportamento que espero utilizando o ajax do primafaces

Comment: O erro de validação que dá quando coloca para processar o `factoryCode` junto é por causa do `required="true"`?

Comment: Chegou a tentar algo como `required="#{MenuManageBean.requestDTO.levelNo ne '0'}"`?

Comment: Se essa alternativa não funcionar, acho que o jeito é ir via JavaScript, desabilitando na mão, no onchange: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9651552/1064325

Comment: 1 O erro que dá, sim é o required true  @falsarella

Comment: required="#{MenuManageBean.requestDTO.levelNo ne '0'}" já está assim, ele não valida, mas caso estiver preenchido ele apaga porque preciso dar update no form para ele reconhecer e o levelNo como 0. Porque caso no de update ele ainda acha que MenuManageBean.requestDTO.levelNo não é 0 e não valida

Comment: Em qual situação ele cai em disabledFieldsLevelZero==false? Pode ser que ele está apagando nesse caso?

Comment: funciona com o fluxo da tela perfeitamente, mas ele não valida pq para o "backend", ou seja, a lista de componente o valor do levelNo ainda não foi alterado então ele não valida quando ele tem que validar, por causa do codigo ** required="#{MenuManageBean.requestDTO.levelNo ne '0'}"**

Comment: Ele apaga porque o process está `@this`. Você precisa colocar `@form` tbm, ou pelo menos esses dos campos, senão o update vai trazer o valor antigo mesmo.

Comment: se eu colocar @form ele valida, pq posso estar mudando de 1 para dois, por exemplo, e nesse caso ele não é 0 e valida.

Comment: Sobre a solução JavaScript, ao invés de colocar a lógica de desabilitar/habilitar no onchange, coloque no oncomplete ou no onsuccess do p:ajax.

Comment: Estranho ele validar. Será que seria `ne 0`, ao invés de `ne '0'`? Qual é o tipo da variável `levelNo`?

Comment: Ah, sim, e esqueci de mencionar que na solução vida JavaScript, você trocaria o process e o update para `@this`.